# What kind of data format is this for PHP

Tags: php

I have a api call using PHP and cURL where I am getting json data back. One of the returned value is for a time field which I need to use to calculate how long until this time. But the time is showing in this format:

```
2019-03-12T16:53:32Z
```

It has a letter T and the letter Z at the end. How do I use this to figure out how long left until this time?

Comment: Hint: use `strtotime()` to parse the value. Besides that, there are plenty of questions to answer your question

Comment: That's a [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) datetime string.

Comment: That's an ISO date and time. `T` separates the date from the time, `Z` means it's UTC.

Comment: @mario In PHP, it is `DateTime::ATOM` or `DATE_ATOM` due to compatibility reasons (http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php#datetime.constants.types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an ISO8601 date format and can easily be used with the DateTime class in PHP like this.

```
$in = '2019-03-12T20:53:32Z';

$ind = new DateTime($in);
echo $ind->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');  // check its correctly initialised

$diff = $ind->diff(new DateTime());  // diff between NOW and that datetime

echo $diff->format('Time till that datetime - %m month, %d days, %h Hours, %m Minutes, %s Seconds');
```

RESULT

```
2019/03/12 20:53:32

Time till that datetime - 0 month, 0 days, 4 Hours, 0 Minutes, 7 Seconds
```